# iOS: How to copy the project resource from Mac to app's document directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, shell, bundle

I have some assets which are used for the app's runtime, normally, they should be copied to the main bundle and load it in app's runtime, like the common image assets.

However they are not the image assets at this time, but some big pdf document files. I don't want to copy them to the main bundle when building the project (*Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources*) **as I found it decreases the signing time obviously.**

The pdf documents' size is about 500MB, that's really a large proportion of the whole main bundle.

From the Objective-C side, it could get the *Documents* path for writing, but not the project resource path. For the shell side, it could get the project resource path, but not the *Documents* path. I check the *export* variables list from a sample *Run Script Phase* output, I didn't found any paths related the *Documents*.

I knew that it's different from the client user's installing progress which is just downloading the main bundle from App Store or others. My final purpose is to find some ways to copy the large files to *Documents* folder for debugging without wasting the signing time. I didn't like the solution that taking the main bundle path as a temporary storage path for copying, really.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, could you use smaller (i.e. non-production) files for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes, we used the small files before, now we need to debug the big files for some logic reasons. @Losiowaty